# If in a ring every ideal is principal, then it has a multiplicative identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If in a ring every ideal is principal, then it has a multiplicative identity.

If the ring is an integral domain, then $R=(a)$, then $a=ra$. Then $rra=ra$. Then it seems $r$ is an identity. But I am confusing to show it in a general ring.

Comment: Please, state whether the ring is supposed to be commutative and what you mean by “principal ideal”. If you mean that every ideal is generated by an element, then the statement is not true and $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a counterexample; note that the least ideal containing an element $a$ is $Ra+\mathbb{Z}a$. If “principal ideal“ means being of the form $Ra$, then it's true.

Comment: The ring is not supposed to be commutative. And principal here means each ideal has the form Ra. So in this case, 2$\mathbb{Z}$ is not a counter example.

Comment: Well, $Ra$ is not necessarily an ideal, you surely know.

Comment: What an unusual problem. Where did it come from, @Connor ?

Comment: @rschwieb it comes from a problem set. Maybe we should assume the ring is commutative.

Comment: @Connor If so, then lhf's solution is sufficient. But we should be sure to impress upon you that this definition of "principal ideal" is not standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

As you've noticed, there is $r\in R$ such that $a=ra$.

Take $b\in R=Ra$. Then $b=sa=sra=rsa=rb$.

(This assumes that $R$ is commutative. And it only uses that $R$ is a principal ideal of the form $Ra$.)

Comment: It assumes commutativity but the question is how do we know it? Given at hand it's not given.

Comment: @ZelosMalum: If we don't assume commutativity, we won't even know what $(a)$ is. So I suppose OP meant to assume that.